# Java configuring timeout for specific session variables

Tags: java, servlets, session-variables, session-timeout

I know the `web.xml` file allows to set the timeout for all of the session variables. But is there a way to configure the timeout for specific session variables (like for error message etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the session is the session, and it times out "all at once".

You may want to consider some form of "conversation scope"; there are several ways to implement this, most use a filter/interceptor of some sort.